# How to limit vertically the extent of an OpenLayers map?

Tags: openlayers-2

When I pan north, the map goes out and I see the white background of my HTML. I want to pan vertically and the map to block when it reaches the top (or bottom, respectively).

I have tried to put bounds, but this solution puts also bounds horizontally. I want to be able to pan infinitely left or right, but limit the panning up and down.

How could I do this?

[image: Map out on pan north]

Answer (score 1):

To limit panning, the correct property to set is restrictedExtent, with a Bounds object in the same projection as the map. Unfortunately, I don't think there's a way of panning infinitely left and right if you set this value, since you would have to set left and right values.

Comment: I tried it, but as you say, it limits the map horizontally, too. I want infinite horizontal and finite vertical panning.

Comment: To get this kind of functionality, you'll probably have to hack the OL map move method - make it return if the user exceeds certain latitudes.